# duda sobre creacion de relacion en modelo laravel

Tags: laravel, relaciones

por mas que he leido, visto la documentacion y viendo ejemplos no puedo aclararme del todo con el tema de las relaciones. En este caso en puntual tengo que obtener datos de una tabla padre (ingresos) una tabla pivot (det_ingresos) y una tercer tabla (bodegas) obteniendo algo asi:
**1.- Martillo -> serie plus 500, mango ergonomico -> Bodega Central**

Por logica deberia ser una relacion M:M, pero no se si tengo que definir algo en el modelo bodega para poder obtener cierta informacion de esta tabla.

Actualmente en el modelo IngresoMaterial estoy probando con una relacion asi (para relacionarme con la tabla pivote det_ingreso_materials)
:

```
  public function detalle_ingreso_materiales()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(IngresoMaterial::class)->using(DetIngresoMaterial::class);
    }
```

y En el controlador buscaria los datos asi:

```
 public function detIngresoParaSeriado($id){

         $ingreso = IngresoMaterial::has('detalle_ingreso_materiales')->get();

        /* $ingreso = IngresoMaterial::with('det_ingreso_materials')->findOrFail($id);
        $detalle = DetIngresoMaterial::all()->where('ingreso_material_id','=',$id);
       $bodega = Bodega::select('nombre_bodega')->where('id',$detalle->bodega_id); */
        //dd($bodega);
        //dd($ingreso);
        return view('bodega.logistica.detIngresoSeriado', compact('ingreso'));

    }
```

Si las relaciones estuvieran bien planteadas, como podria acceder desde una vista blade a la informacion de las tres tablas?, al intentar acceder a la vista me da el siguiente error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'proyecto.ingreso_material_ingreso_material' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from` ingreso_materials`where exists (select * from`ingreso_materials`as`laravel_reserved_0`inner join`ingreso_material_ingreso_material`on`laravel_reserved_0`.`id`=`ingreso_material_ingreso_material`.`ingreso_material_id`where`ingreso_materials`.`id`=`ingreso_material_ingreso_material`.`ingreso_material_id`))`

Saludos a todos

Comment: Hola @BetaM, o sea para traer los datos (incluidos los de la tabla intermedia) solo haciendo las relaciones en el modelo IngresoMaterial (hacia la tabla det_ingreso, la tabla bodega)?

Comment: mmm oka, entonces por ejemplo en mi modelo IngresoMaterial puedo definir asi:    public function detalle_ingreso_materiales()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(IngresoMaterial::class)->using(DetIngresoMaterial::class);
    }

Comment: La tabla que dice no encontrar es la tabla intermedia cierto?

Comment: no, segun el error es la tabla ingreso_materials, la que vendria siendo la tabla primaria, en la que se inserta primero